# Dash.js player doesn't play when debug

Tags: ripple, multi-device-hybrid-apps, mpeg-dash

I've embedded dash.js player into Multi Device Hybrid App template, feed it with working live video link (tested with the same dash.js in trivial html page). When app is starting in Ripple (Apache Ripple™, web based mobile environment simulator), I see debug info in VS with errors "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". After a few attempts it stops to try and doesn't play a thing.

However, to check if network is working between client and server I've created a website with test image on the server side and embedded this image into application on the client side. It manages to load it, so at least network is working. Firewall disabled both sides.

So, the same exact MPEG DASH manifest is working inside an html with embedded dash.js in Chrome browser, but doesn't work when in Hybrid App in Ripple. But remote image can be loaded inside that app, so network is fine and Ripple let the app to request remote resources from the net.

What the reason? How can I debug it?

Comment: Please clarify what this "Ripple" is - the question is not easily understandable.

Comment: Apache Ripple, web based mobile environment simulator. I thought that multi-device-hybrid-apps tag has set the context.

Answer (score 0):

Is the HTML5 MSE (Media Source Extentions) supported within Ripple? You may also try it with some basic sample code like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn551368(v=vs.85).aspx) or [this](http://dash-mse-test.appspot.com/dash-player.html), or try another DASH web player like [dash-js](http://www-itec.uni-klu.ac.at/dash/?page_id=746) or [bitdash](http://www.dash-player.com)